# How do I select a row based on a priority value in another row?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11G and I have a table with the following columns and values and I want to select the value for each column based on the priority column.  I only want one row for each ID.

```
ID    NAME   NAME_PRIORITY   COLOR   COLOR_PRIORITY
1     SAM       2             RED          1
1     SAM       2             GREEN        2
1     JOHN      1             BLUE         3
2     MARY      2             ORANGE       1
3     JON       2             RED          2
3     PETE      3             GREEN        1
```

Desired Results

```
ID   NAME    NAME_PRIORITY   COLOR     COLOR_PRIORITY
1    JOHN       1             RED           1
2    MARY       2             ORANGE        1
3    JON        2             GREEN         1
```

How do I select the NAME and COLOR with the lowest PRIORITY # and only have one row for each ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one option is:

```
select d.id, min(name) keep (dense_rank first order by name_priority) name,
       min(name_priority) name_priority,
       min(color) keep (dense_rank first order by color_priority) color,
       min(color_priority) color_priority
  from yourtab d
 group by id;
```

Comment: +1 That is slick, I did not know about `keep`.  Here is a demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab996/5

Comment: Thanks I never knew about keep!  I was going to try something a bit more complicated like the answers below.  This is much simpler, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) on both the `name_priority` and `color_priority` to get the result:

```
select n.id,
  name, 
  name_priority,
  color,
  color_priority
from
(
  select id,
    name, 
    name_priority,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by name_priority) name_row
  from yourtable
) n
inner join
(
  select id,
    color, 
    color_priority,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by color_priority) color_row
  from yourtable
) c
  on n.id = c.id
  and n.name_row = c.color_row
where n.name_row = 1
  and c.color_row = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab996/1).

Once you have the `row_number()` for each priority, then you will join the results on the `id` and the row number and only return the rows where the row number is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

This query uses `Common Table Expression` and `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
WITH nameList
AS
(
    SELECT  ID, Name,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID 
                            ORDER BY NAME_PRIORITY) rn
    FROM    TableName
),
colorList
AS
(
    SELECT  a.ID, a.Name,
            b.Color, b.COLOR_PRIORITY,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID 
                            ORDER BY COLOR_PRIORITY) rnB
    FROM    nameList a
            INNER JOIN tableName b
                ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.rn = 1
)
SELECT  ID, Name, Color, COLOR_PRIORITY
FROM    colorList
WHERE   rnB = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/613c9/12)