# Select row based on identifier and value from another row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL dataset that looks like this:

```
ID    PARENT_ID    VALUE

1     100          This comment should be approved
2     100          Y
3     101          Another approved comment
4     101          Y
5     102          This comment is not approved
6     102          N
```

I need to construct an SQL query to select the rows that have a matching parent_id and corresponding value of Y (but ignore the rows with single letters as a value in the result) to result in:

```
ID    PARENT_ID    VALUE

1     100          This comment should be approved
3     101          Another approved comment
```

My idea is to use `GROUP BY` to combine the columns, but I can't work out how to select based on the Y/N values.

There is possibly a solution here [How do I select a row based on a priority value in another row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252347/how-do-i-select-a-row-based-on-a-priority-value-in-another-row) but I don't think it is asking quite the same question.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can express this as an aggregation, you can express this using `exists`:

```
select d.*
from dataset d
where d.value <> 'Y' and
      exists (select 1
              from dataset d2
              where d2.parent_id = d.parent_id and d2.value = 'Y'
             );
```

This version is probably more efficient.

Comment: As Nick points out this is better performance-wise, but my SQL is actually part of a larger query that makes this technique difficult. This is probably the better solution for most use cases.

Comment: After some updating of my full query I have managed to integrate this approach so updating to the preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you possibly can, change your table schema. Your table is storing two kinds of data in the same field (yes no flags and comments). This breaks normality and will haunt you later.

But if its not your table to change, you will need to self join. Try this.

```
   SELECT a.id, a.parent_Id, a.value 
   FROM table a inner join table b
   ON a.parent_id =b.parent_id
    WHERE a.value <> 'Y' and b.value ='Y'
```

Comment: Unfortunately the table schema isn't mine to update. I had tried joining the table to self but it hadn't worked as my WHERE statement was incorrect. This solution works great.